# how to send my dynamic price to buy now paypal button

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I wanna know to to send dynamic price to my paypal button. This is the javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
```

I wanna take the price value and send it to the paypal buy now button
and this is the paypal button:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BAX7KCUXKPXGG">
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the type of button you have generated, it seems to be impossible to dynamically change the price as the ID of the button that was saved in a merchant's PayPal account. PayPal assigns the value when payment buttons are first created and saved in merchants' PayPal accounts.

I found this information [in the paypal developer docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/) while trying to figure out what `<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="BAX7KCUXKPXGG">` meant. I think you might find [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#individual-items-variables) part of the docs useful as it seems like you're trying to individually price items

Comment: ye you are right elena , i found out that i had to take another button code and iam still having a problem , well  it has this code <input type="hidden" name="amount" value = 20">     which its value can be changed , i tried to change it and it is working but i wanna it to get the value from my variable so i changed the code to  <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="finalpaypal"> ,  and added this code in my javascirpy                  document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value= price;  but that doesnt work .. i hope someone can help

Comment: It would really help if you posted how that variable is defined and try to explain exactly what isn't working... Putting in `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">` and running this in the js `document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value= price; ` should work, if my "work" you mean change the value of that input

Comment: At first i was trying to check if i can change price by myself or not  so i changed the value of this code <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="20">   to 30/40 .. etc and it is working and the price changes when i click buy now  ~  now  i really  want is to send  the value of "price variable" to this code so i had to change it to "id" instead of value  like this   <input type="hidden" name="amount" id="finalpaypal" >     and i added in my script    document.getElementById("finalpaypal").value = price;  but i dont know why it is not working ...